# How to specify a database fields configuration based on a JSON array with MarkLogic server?

Tags: json, search, indexing, configuration, marklogic

With MarkLogic server (version 8), I am trying to define a field configuration (`suggest`) which should use the contents/values of a JSON array (`descriptions`), the definition for the database fields configuration looks like:

```
        <fields>
            <field>
                <field-name>suggest</field-name>
                <include-root>false</include-root>
                <stemmed-searches>advanced</stemmed-searches>
                <word-searches>true</word-searches>
                <field-value-searches>true</field-value-searches>
                <field-value-positions>true</field-value-positions>
                <trailing-wildcard-searches>true</trailing-wildcard-searches>
                <trailing-wildcard-word-positions>true</trailing-wildcard-word-positions>
                <three-character-searches>true</three-character-searches>
                <three-character-word-positions>true</three-character-word-positions>
                <word-lexicons>
                    <word-lexicon>http://marklogic.com/collation/</word-lexicon>
                </word-lexicons>
                <included-elements>
                    <included-element>
                        <namespace-uri/>
                        <localname>descriptions</localname>
                        <weight>1.0</weight>
                        <attribute-namespace-uri/>
                        <attribute-localname/>
                        <attribute-value/>
                    </included-element>
                </included-elements>
                <excluded-elements/>
                <tokenizer-overrides/>
            </field>
        </fields>
```

And a sample document instance:

```
{
   "descriptions": ["lorem", "ipsum"]
}
```

Unfortunately the content seems not to be indexed, and therefore no results are given back for suggest queries. Please advise on how you have to define the configuration to index the JSON array values.

The following sections in the documentation I read, but could not find info on this specific topic:

- Administrators Guide: "Fields Database Settings"
  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields
- Application Developer's Guide: "Working with JSON: Creating Indexes and Lexicons Over JSON Documents": http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_18265

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [adding a field range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_65763) on that field.

The field itself is already indexed, but only as a hash index for word and value queries. [For search suggestions you want a range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_18231), which stores a list of values rather than hashes. This is sometimes called a value lexicon.

For example I added your `suggest` field and a field range index on `suggest` as string, with the unicode codepoint collation. The config XML looks like:

```
<range-field-indexes>
  <range-field-index>
    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
    <collation>http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</collation>
    <field-name>suggest</field-name>
    <range-value-positions>false</range-value-positions>
    <invalid-values>reject</invalid-values>
  </range-field-index>
</range-field-indexes>
```

I used the codepoint collation out of habit, but you could use whatever collation you prefer. That range index can be tested in XQuery: the collation in the XQuery **must** match the configuration.

```
cts:values(
  cts:field-reference(
    'suggest', 'collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint'))
```

That produces a sequence of string values:

```
ipsum
lorem
```

Assuming you're using the REST API, you should be able to do something similar with the [`/suggest` endpoint](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/suggest).